# Azure REST API returns HTML of page

Tags: azure, api, rest, asp.net-core, blazor

I have deployed my full-stack solution into Azure, containing front-end in Blazor and REST API created in ASP .NET Core. All of the endpoints work except one, which si `GET api/shows`. When I try to call this via Postman or directly in Azure, then it works fine, but when my front-end tries to call it, then it returns HTML of the index page.

I have managed to get it running yesterday, but now I have published a new version of the front-end and it is not working, again. It looks like Azure does not set request headers, because the one to `api/shows` has `Content-Type: text/html`, but in Azure I set headers to be `Content-Type: application/json`.

In Azure I have set Inbound and Outbound policies to:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Accept" exists-action="append">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="append">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Accept" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

These are the response headers of `GET api/shows`

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1401
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 03 Jan 2021 15:41:58 GMT
ETag: "652521af3d0d61:0"
Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Dec 2020 01:55:31 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

while other requests, f.e. fetching shows by date `GET api/shows/02-01-2021` has

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 122
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 03 Jan 2021 15:55:19 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

In the Shows controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieShow>>> Get()
{
  var shows = await _mediator.Send(new GetShowsQuery());
  return Ok(shows);
}
```

EDIT: For fun, I have tried to re-enabling caching in the browser. Suddenly it works fine.

Comment: " then it returns HTML of the index page" I guess the pronoun "it" refers to the Web Api, right ? How can the Web Api have access to the index page html ? Is the index page (that is actually the Index component) is displayed instead of the page from which you were trying to perform the Web Api call ? From my experience( not personal one, but that gathered from reading questions in SO), an exception is thrown in Blazor by SYSTEM.NET.HTTP.JSON because it cannot deserialize  the response data as it is Html and not JSON as expected...Is this the case with your issue ? Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Re-enabling caching in the browser solved the problem. In Chrome, this can be done by opening DevTools (F12). In the Network tab, there is a checkbox for Disable Cache.

Turned it on, refreshed the page and then turned it off worked for me.